# MySQL Count Query not working but its display records list

Tags: php, mysql, count

I try to use this Query to get Number of Records bu tits not display count in phpMyAdmin

And also give me the wrong result when i try to remove LIMIT from Query..

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM fm_detail
  LEFT JOIN lang ON lang.l_id = fm_detail.language_id
  LEFT JOIN country ON country.c_id = fm_detail.country_id
  LEFT JOIN users ON users.usr_id = fm_detail.submitter_id
  LEFT JOIN category ON category.cat_id = fm_detail.category_id
  INNER JOIN city ON fm_detail.city_fm = city.city_id 
  where 1=1 AND fm_detail.category_id = '1' LIMIT 10 , 5
```

This query did not give me any Record Count..

But when i use..

```
  SELECT * FROM fm_detail
  LEFT JOIN lang ON lang.l_id = fm_detail.language_id
  LEFT JOIN country ON country.c_id = fm_detail.country_id
  LEFT JOIN users ON users.usr_id = fm_detail.submitter_id
  LEFT JOIN category ON category.cat_id = fm_detail.category_id
  INNER JOIN city ON fm_detail.city_fm = city.city_id 
  where 1=1 AND fm_detail.category_id = '1' LIMIT 10 , 5
```

This give me the Records list in PHPMYADMIN..

I don't know how to use this query to fix my problem.

Please help me asap..

Thanks,

Comment: 1. You don't need to wrap quotes around int values. 2. You can just do `select count(*) FROM` instead of `select count(*) as num`.

Comment: Not working.. just empty count.

Answer (score 3):

Because you use COUNT function (which in your case returns one row) and LIMIT clause that starts from 10 record. So, you do not get any records at all.

Comment: any Another way to get number of records count?

Comment: I don't see SUM in the query.  Do you mean COUNT?  Presuming you do, might be helpful to provide the corrected query for the asker.

Comment: @Muhammad Remove the limit. If you're actually keen on the limit do a SELECT COUNT( SELECT yourselectquery ) AS number;

Comment: i don't understand.. i can't count records without join the query.. its not give me the correct result.

Comment: @Conspicuous Compiler Yes, I meant aggregate function - COUNT.

Comment: @Muhammad You can use a subquery, e.g. - SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 10, 5) t

Comment: @Devart i am trying this query.. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM fm_detail as fms
LEFT JOIN lang as lag ON lag.l_id = fms.language_id 
LEFT JOIN country as coun ON coun.c_id = fms.country_id 
LEFT JOIN users as usr ON usr.usr_id = fms.submitter_id 
LEFT JOIN category as cat ON  cat.cat_id = fms.category_id 
INNER JOIN city as city ON citys.city_fm = fms.city_id 
where 1=1 AND fms.category_id = '1' LIMIT 0, 10);` and also i use `my Q query` but its give me the [Err] 1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Have a look at my query, it has a `t` alias. Add alias name after the subquery - SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table) AS alias.

Answer (score 0):

About the LIMIT... maybe `select distinct` will help to get the right count. Joins sometimes create duplicated rows.

Comment: Nothing help.. is there any way i can count number of records by using php?

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() => count()